# How to return the key with the most associated values inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I currently have a HashMap in the form 'HashMap<String, HashSet>', which contains a key (an item) and a value (a HashSet of all items associated with that item).

I am trying to write a method within the class that retrieves the key (item) with the most values (items) associated with it and am not sure how to do this, for example:

Input:

```
myItems.mostValues();
```

Output:

```
Item1 is has the most interactions, as it is connected to 3 items: {X, Y, Z}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: [Sergei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176614/how-to-return-the-key-with-the-most-associated-values-inside-a-hashmap/66176932#66176932)'s answer handles null and is O(n) using streams. [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176614/how-to-return-the-key-with-the-most-associated-values-inside-a-hashmap/66177001#66177001)'s answer outputs all the possible values

### Streams with sort (less efficient) - O(nlogn)

1. Stream the elements
2. Reverse sort by `size` of `Set`
3. Get the key of the element (or value directly and print it)
4. If key is retrieved, then lookup the key in myItems and print value

```java
myItems.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
  .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().size() - a.getValue().size())
  .findFirst().orElse(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(null, null))
  .getValue());
```

### Normal for loop - O(n)

1. Iterate over all entires
2. Keep track of max size at each iteration

```java
  int maxItem = 0;
  Set<String> maxValues = null;
  for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> e : myItems.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getValue() == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (maxItem < e.getValue().size()) {
      maxValues = e.getValue();
      maxItem = maxValues.size();
    }
 }
```

### Updated: Since the answer was accepted, i will add the other O(n) solutions with null handling on top of Sergey and Sergei answers.

The following code assumes initial Map is non null.

#### Get maximum one- Stream O(n)

1. Stream values
2. Ignore null values
3. Get the max sized value (optional)
4. if empty, then return null

```java
Map<String, Set<String>> myItems = new HashMap<>(); // input
myItems.put("a", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
myItems.put("b", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("b", "c")));

Set<String> result = myItems.values().stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull) // get only non-null
  .max(Comparator.comparing(Set::size)) // get the max size
  .orElse(null); // avoid optional.get() error incase of no results - can use new HashSet<>() also
```

### Stream - Get all Maximum - O(n)

#### Find maximum size (or -1 if no elements)

1. Stream values
2. Ignore null values
3. Transform to value to its size
4. Find max size
5. Stream values
6. Ignore null values
7. Select values with size as max size
8. Collect all the values as `List`

```java
Map<String, Set<String>> myItems = new HashMap<>(); // input
myItems.put("a", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
myItems.put("b", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z")));
myItems.put("c", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a")));

List<Set<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
myItems.values().stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull) // get only non-null
  .mapToInt(Set::size)
  .max()
  .ifPresent(val -> myItems.values().stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(v -> v.size() == val)
    .forEach(v -> result.add(v)));
```

### Usage of Streams with lambda/method references

1. Whenever possible try to use the method references using `::` as this helps to understand the object type(`Set::size`) when required and abstracts type for common operations(`Objects::nonNull`).
2. In real code, always handle null (even with Optional)

Comment: Not a critique, just added info: The above solutions all assume that the values can never be null. If OP can have null values in his map instead of initialized HashSets he would have to handle those cases by adding null checks before calling size() on the values.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, Thank you for the feedback and i have updated the answer with `null` checks. Also, will add any future answers with complete check. Thanks for taking your time to check the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
                .map(entry -> map.get(entry.getKey()));
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the optimized version(i missed this completely). You don't need the cast though.

Comment: thanks for pointing out! I've just removed redundant cast

Answer (score 2):

```
 map.values()
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToInt(val -> val.size())
    .max()
    .ifPresent(val-> map.keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(key-> map.get(key) != null && map.get(key).size() == val)
            .forEach(System.out::println)
    );
```

Comment: Good, another O(n) solution. As per `Sergei`s answer, you can add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` after stream to handle `null` to make it a complete answer.

Comment: Thanx, @Horse, I've added

Comment: I think, you may need to add null check inside `ifPresent` also, else `map.get(key).size()` might throw NPE

Comment: @horse I put checking

Comment: @SergeyAfinogenov there's a typo in comparator, `e2` is missing.  `Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size())` could be used as it is less verbose

Comment: yes @Alex Rudenko you are right and in this case I came to the same solution as SergeiTonoian so I removed that